# ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to install python `SpeechRecognition` on my machine.When i am trying to install the package as `pip install SpeechRecognition`. I am getting the following error.

```
import json, urllib.request

ImportError: No module named request
```

And then i referred and installed requests as `pip install requests` i am i am getting `Requirement already satisfied`.But still i am unable to install `SpeechRecognition`.Please let me know what mistake i am doing.Thanks in advance

Comment: You are running Python 3 code on Python 2; the Python 2 `urllib` and `urllib2` modules were merged into `urllib.request`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Then how can i do this in python 2.7

Comment: You can't, not with this package.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `SpeechRecognition` library [requires Python 3.3 or up](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition):

> #### Requirements
>
> [...]
>
> The first software requirement is Python 3.3 or better. This is required to use the library.

and from the Trove classifiers:

> Programming Language :: Python
>   Programming Language :: Python :: 3
>   Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
>   Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4

The [`urllib.request` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) is part of the Python 3 standard library; in Python 2 you'd use `urllib2` here.

Comment: urllib2 does not hold request parameter

Comment: No, it doesn't. Did you expect it would? Python 3 moved several things into a package namespace, one of those things is the Python 2  `urllib2` module.

Comment: Yes, why do you think there would be a `urllib2.request` attribute? There isn't supposed to be one.

Comment: What do you mean by "in Python 2 you'd use urllib2 here." ? It sounds like  urllib2.request exists in Python 2.7 .. That's why Tejas Tank asked. (of course I know in urllib.request exists in Python3)

Comment: @ChanKim: I mean that you can replace `import urllib.request` with `import urllib2`, nothing more, nothing less. Not that that will help the OP, as the package they are installing doesn't support Python 2 and will have other issues.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I found the modules that were in urllib.request are now in urllib2 in Python2. So instead of `from urllib.requests import urlopen` we can do `from urllib2 import urlopen`. I now realize the last sentence of your answer meant this.

Comment: @ChanKim: Python 2 came first, so you have the chronology the wrong way around there. Note that Python 2 reaches its end of life in [just over 9 months](https://pythonclock.org/), if you are starting any new projects you really, **really** want to use Python 3.

Answer (score 33):

You can do that using Python 2.

1. Remove `request`
2. Make that line: `from urllib2 import urlopen`

You cannot have `request` in Python 2, you need to have Python 3 or above.

Comment: Good solution for Python 2 settings.

Comment: I've tried: `proxy_handler = urlopen.ProxyHandler({
    'http': super_proxy_url,
    'https': super_proxy_url,
})
opener = urlopen.build_opener(proxy_handler)` and got an Error: _proxy_handler = urlopen.ProxyHandler({
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ProxyHandler'_ What's wrong?

Answer (score 13):

from [@Zzmilanzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7340384/zzmilanzz-zzmadubashazz)'s answer I used

```
try: #python3
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except: #python2
    from urllib2 import urlopen
```