# Python 2 + Flask - ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, flask, pip

I'm trying to install [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), using pip.

Running the most basic:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I get `ImportError: No module named request`

`python --version` returns `Python 2.7.6`

`pip show flask` returns `version: 0.10.1`

From what I've been able to find, the [`request` module is Python 3 related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652074/importerror-no-module-named-request) and says to use `urllib2`.

So I've added `import urllib2`, then get:

```
  ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try this in a virtualenv? If It's a global environment, maybe there's a package conflict that causes this.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a **virtualenv** worked for me. Following steps on this page http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/#virtualenv you do:

```
pip install virtualenv

virtualenv MY_NAME

. MY_NAME/bin/activate

pip install Flask

python index.py
```

To make basic Flask app running inside your MY_NAME virtualenv.